# Package does not exist in command prompt

Tags: java, jar, cmd, package, lang

I have this line in my code:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
```

I downloaded the Apache Commons Lang 2.6 zip from `http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi`. There were two choices for Binaries, 1) `commons-lang-2.6-bin.tar.gz` and 2) `commons-lang-2.6-bin.zip`. I downloaded the second one and then extracted it. Then I went to the properties for my project and added the commons-lang-2.6 JAR file to my build path (there were two others - javadoc & sources). Then I go to my command prompt and try to do a `gradle clean build` to see if I'll get a successful build and it says `error: org.apache.commons.lang does not exist`. Any help to get rid of this error? I'm using myEclipse and it doesn't give me that error, only my cmd does.

Comment: I don't think you could have added the jar to your build path correctly. Post what you changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you added the jar in your eclipse build path. However, this usually doesn't mean you added it to you gradle build script, which means gradle doesn't know about the commons-lang jar file, only eclipse does.

To add it to gradle, you should add it to the build.gradle file, more or less as follows :

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.3.2'
}
```

Maybe you could try using a gradle plugin for ecplise, like https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/ to automate or make easier to keep ecplise and the gradle script in sync.

Comment: I added this to my build file and it got rid of those errors. Thanks!

Comment: This worked great for commons-lang3 but I have to add one for commons-net too. This is my whole dependencies code:

dependencies {
 testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
 compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.3.2'
 compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-net', version: '3.3'
  }

and cmd is saying it could not find org.apache.commons:commons-net:3.3

Comment: it gives Error:Failed to resolve: org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the classpath for your build script is properly defined.